# How to find highest key value from hashmap

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

iterate with max key value so that it will replace max string value. first My code is

```
HashMap<String, String> mapp=new HashMap<String, String>();
mapp.put("ab","blue");
mapp.put("abc","black");
mapp.put("abcd","pink");
for (Iterator it = alltyp.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    String finalstring = (String) it.next();

    Iterator it1=mapp.entrySet().iterator();
    while(it1.hasNext())
    {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) it1.next();
        String key_ = (String) pairs.getKey();
        String value_ = (String) pairs.getValue();
        finalstring = finalstring.replaceAll(key_, value_);      
    }
}
```

I want to iterate with max key value means key value "abcd" should iterate first then "abc" then "ab".

Answer (score 13):

Here is an example using Collections.max().  You can also pass a comparator if you want a custom ordering.

```java
HashMap<String, String> mapp=new HashMap<String, String>();
mapp.put("ab","blue");
mapp.put("abc","black");
mapp.put("abcd","pink");

// find max key alphabetically
String maxKey = Collections.max(mapp.keySet());


Comparator<String> strLenCmp = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1.length(), o2.length());
    }
};

// find max key by key length
String longKey = Collections.max(mapp.keySet(), strLenCmp);
```

*Edit*: added example with custom Comparator

Comment: how to pass comparator?

Comment: updated answer with compator code snippet.  Please accept the answer if you are happy with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is giving an error on compare. I want to iterate greater key value first (means in descending order) so that my replaceall function should replace greater value first. please give ur suggetion.

Comment: The example I gave compiles ok for me.  What error do you get?  The default comparitor for Strings is probably what you need if you want to find the greatest key.

Answer (score 2):

Use Generics, get rid of the casting. That will tidy up your code a lot.

You will need a custom comparator to do the sorting.

Once you have the comparator you have two choices:

**Option 1:**

Create an ArrayList, dump all the keys from the map into it.

Sort the ArrayList, iterate over the sorted ArrayList.

**Option 2:**

Use a TreeMap to store the data.

Comment: Yeah go with a TreeMap for this purpose

Comment: @DavidRoussel The drawback with the TreeMap is you are tied to one sorting order. With option 1 you can sort the same data multiple ways, so it's worth having both options available.

Comment: Good poing Tim, I've posted an answer with an example of Collections.max().

Answer (score 0):

Try using the TreeMap instead of HashMap it has the method for getting the last entry which will give you the entry which has the highest value of key. Even in TreeMap if you pass your custom Comparator then it will be sorted in a way that you will get the key with max value first so you don't have to worry about it.

[TreeMap - lastEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#lastEntry%28%29)

Refer this link, and lastEntry method.

Comment: You just get the list of entries of keys using keySet() method and iterate through it.