# Sort HashMap by Key Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a HashMap in which the Key (`int ID`) is determined by finding the previous number + 1.

I'm relatively new to java and the examples I see on other posts of SO seem quite confusing.

My Existing code:

```
public class Office
{
   private Map<Integer, Employee> employee = new HashMap<>();

   /**
    * Constructor for objects of class Office
    */
   public Office()
   {
      employee = new HashMap<>();
   }

   public void addOffice(int ID, String Name, String JobTitle, int Age, int Salary)
   {
      Employee e = new Employee(ID, Name, JobTitle, Age, Salary);
      employee.put(ID, e);
   }

   public int getID()
   {
      #find info
   }
}
```

I'm looking for psuedo code of:

```
   public int getID()
   {
      int i = 0;
      if (Collections.sort(employee.Key[0] > 0))
      {
         i = (Collections.sort(employee.Key[0] > 0)
         i = i + 1;
         return 
      }
      else
      {
         return 0 
      }
   }
```

I've looked on the Oracle website but cannot make head nor toe of it.

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Why don't you use a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) ?

Comment: (TreeMap implements [SortedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html))

Comment: Thanks @Michael then how could I abstract the last `key` value?

Comment: "sort" and "HashMap" are contradictory terms, any hash based container is basically non-sortable. You need a sortable map, e.g. `TreeMap`, as the others already suggested. Alternatively you could use `LinkedHashMap` which internally also maintains a linked list that is sorted by insertion order.

Comment: I suggest to design this code from the outside. How do you want to use this `Office` class? What's the purpose of the `getId()` method?

Comment: @TamasRev So I am adding a list of users to a set and I want the ID (Key) to be whatever the previous key was + 1 - hope that makes sense.

Comment: If you want a map which goes `1 -> {a}, 2 -> {b}, 3 -> {c}` isn't that just a list...?

Comment: @SCramphorn that makes sense. However, `addOffice()` receives the `ID` from the outside so you must choose one or another.
Also, what should happen if somebody just deletes the previous employee. Is it ok to reuse its id? Is it ok to reuse other deleted id-s?
As Michael pointed out, why isn't a list good for you?

Comment: @TamasRev I'll be honest, the module i'm studying focuses on Maps so perhaps I didn't think of using anything else (it doesn't state I have to use one). Could you possibly link how to use a list in the same way then? Thanks

Comment: Looks like all you want is that new employee you are adding should have employee id as "<last_emp_id> + 1", so why don't you keep track of last assigned employee id in a global variable? Traversing a hashmap to just get the last key is an overkill.

Comment: Thanks @Michael but how was myList defined? Could you post an answer which is edited to the class for this? 

Thanks,

Comment: @SCramphorn I've added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably just use a list for this, provided you don't need to remove employees:

```
public class Office
{
   private final List<Employee> employees = new LinkedList<>(); //or ArrayList

   public Office()
   {
      // do nothing
   }

   // FYI variables should start with a lowercase character
   public void addOffice(String name, String jobTitle, int age, int salary)
   {
      Employee e = new Employee(employees.size(), name, jobTitle, age, salary);
      employees.add(e);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael. Last question - what is the point of a 'Final' is that the same as `const` in c# ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with c# but possibly. It means the variable can only ever point to that one object. In this case, it will never point to another list. That one object might change (e.g. adding or removing from the list) so it's not really correct to say it's "constant". Rather, it's a constant reference to an object which may or may not be constant.

Answer (score -1):

If you just need an unique ID as key you can use system timestamp, for example from `System.CurrentTimeMillis()`. Or you can even use randomly generated UIID by calling `java.util.UUID.randomUUID()`.

If you anyway want to have incremental key, then you have to create a method which tries to find maximum key value and increment it.
Here is a related question:
[How to find highest key value from hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200973/how-to-find-highest-key-value-from-hashmap)

Note about thread safety if your class used simultaneously by several threads.

Comment: Both of these are vulnerable to random collisions. This is not a good solution.

Comment: UUID can't have collisions, curent timestamp - might be a solution if map is not used so often, i.e. on just user's action

Comment: UUID most definitely can have collisions, it's just unlikely. There are only so many possibly integers or longs you can represent in Java so if you call UUID often enough, it's inevitable. The key difference between just incrementing a counter and using UUID is that hitting the maximum limit of a counter is predicatable, and getting UUID collisions is not.